# JavaScript Intellisense in Visual Studio Community 2013 with NTVS (Node.js Tools)

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2013, requirejs, ntvs

Using VS2013 Community Edition with Nodejs Tools for Visual Studio, the issue is that the intellisense for js files && classes is not working at all.
Dont have Resharper installed so it is not related to it.
I looked into text editor-> javascript -> auto list member is checked.

I also cannot add reference files to js files in a Project of type "From Existing Node.js Code" or "Blank Nodejs Web Application", also cannot create "_references.js" file neither through Web Essentials neither through Add -> Javascript Intellisense.

The project is front end running on node js.
Basically we use require js to load different modules (backbone : views, models etc ).

So as you see the intellisense it not working for this.getEmptyResponse.
https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/54c0f5ffef5a644796f37cbc/851x222/4fb7e502f05f8b0ad01f2e58aee7241d/intellisense1.png

Also if i you require or define, it also doesnt show up anything.

And i cannot create javascript intellisense file either.
https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/54c0f5ffef5a644796f37cbc/677x466/7e01ade2c13072a9ac8534ac90b7391d/intellisense2.png

Any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: could be that another extension is causing troubles, try disabling all an see if that solves the problem, then enable one by one until you find the extension that's causing it

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?